# powershell script behaves differently in TeamCity

Tags: powershell, teamcity-9.0

Short summary - even though Teamcity agent is setup to run under my credential and looks like it is it's still behaving as though using a less privileged account.

The build Agent service is set to run using my credential and I can see it in the services applet.

The build has a simple powershell script that loads a page in IE using the IE COM object.

```
$IE=new-object -com internetexplorer.application 
$IE.visible=$true 
$IE.navigate2("https://myurl.com/location")
```

I also have a separate command script with maps a network drive to a webDAV location.

```
NET USE Y:  https://myurl.com/location
```

Both of these run fine from the command line.

I've confirmed the scripts are executing under my account
by running

```
echo $([Environment]::UserName)
```

in powershell and using the

whoami

command for the drive mapping script.

for powershell I get the error

```
new-object : Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID 
{0002DF01-0000-0000-C000-000000000046} failed due to the following error:
 80080005 Server execution failed (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80080005
 (CO_E_SERVER_EXEC_FAILURE)).
 At line:1 char:5
 $IE=new-object -com internetexplorer.application
 CategoryInfo          : ResourceUnavailable: (:) [New-Object], COMException
 FullyQualifiedErrorId : NoCOMClassIdentified,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.NewObjectCommand
```

for the drive mapping script I get

```
  "The system cannot find the drive specified."
```

Note I've also tried to run NET USE as part of the script to see what drives are mapped and it's not showing the drive, even if I map it manually before running the script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Might have just stumbled on the answer myself.

Seems running as a windows service has an impact on permissions.

https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD8/Known+Issues#KnownIssues-Windowsservicelimitations

Solution is to start the agent manually outside of the services console.

Comment: yep, that did it, can see and map drives now and the powershell script creates the browser without issue.